# if else statement breaks when a class doesn't exist result in a null

Tags: javascript, if-statement, null, slick.js

I am creating a if/else statement loop to check if a class exist or not. If it exists, grab the html attribute data-id and display its value in the slick carousel initialSlide. If not, it goes on the 2nd else/if to check if a class exist or not, if it does do this. If 1st and 2nd statements fail, then do else statement.

The **locations-slide--active** class is set when the object date match today's day and show that class. If the object dates are in the future days, **locations-slide--active** class will not show and will show only **locations-slide--upcoming-event** instead.

The problem is when the **locations-slide--active** class doesn't exist, it becomes a null and my first if/else loop breaks and doesn't go to 2nd else/if statement.

How do I check the class doesn't exist and if it is a null, it will go on to the 2nd else statement? I think somehow I have to make the loop to understand a class doesn't exist and it is a null but will still go to 2nd else/if statement.

**setActiveSlidePosition** is a variable to set the initialSlide for the slick carousel.

JS

```
  var getActiveSlide = document.querySelector(".locations-slide--active");
  var getUpcomingSlide = document.querySelector(".locations-slide--upcoming-event");

  if (getActiveSlide.classList.contains('locations-slide--active')) {
    var setActiveSlidePosition = getActiveSlide.getAttribute('data-id');
  } else if (getUpcomingSlide.classList.contains('locations-slide--upcoming-event')) {
    var setActiveSlidePosition = getUpcomingSlide.getAttribute('data-id');
  } else {
    var setActiveSlidePosition = 0;
  }
```

HTML with locations-slide--active

```
    <div class="slick-slide slick-active" data-slick-index="2" aria-hidden="false" style="width: 273px;" role="tabpanel" id="slick-slide02">
      <div class="locations-slide locations-slide--past-event" data-id="1">
        <div class="locations-slide-inner">
          <p class="date heading--h3 font--bold text--uppercase">Aug 01 2022</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="locations-slide locations-slide--active" data-id="2">
        <div class="locations-slide-inner">
          <p class="date heading--h3 font--bold text--uppercase">Aug 12 2022</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="locations-slide locations-slide--upcoming-event" data-id="3">
        <div class="locations-slide-inner">
          <p class="date heading--h3 font--bold text--uppercase">Aug 15 2022</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

HTML without locations-slide--active and this class doesn't exist and becomes a null

```
    <div class="slick-slide slick-active" data-slick-index="2" aria-hidden="false" style="width: 273px;" role="tabpanel" id="slick-slide02">
      <div class="locations-slide locations-slide--past-event" data-id="1">
        <div class="locations-slide-inner">
          <p class="date heading--h3 font--bold text--uppercase">Aug 01 2022</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="locations-slide locations-slide--upcoming-event" data-id="2">
        <div class="locations-slide-inner">
          <p class="date heading--h3 font--bold text--uppercase">Aug 14 2022</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="locations-slide locations-slide--upcoming-event" data-id="3">
        <div class="locations-slide-inner">
          <p class="date heading--h3 font--bold text--uppercase">Aug 15 2022</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Hope I explain it well.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#syntax 
Look at the docs: 
"An Element object representing the first element in the document that matches the specified set of CSS selectors, or null is returned if there are no matches"

Comment: You are guaranteed that `getActiveSlide.classList.contains('locations-slide--active')` because `getActiveSlide = document.querySelector(".locations-slide--active")`, unless getActiveSlide doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of directly referencing properties on the object, you can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```
if (getActiveSlide?.classList.contains('locations-slide--active')) {
//                ^--- here
  var setActiveSlidePosition = getActiveSlide.getAttribute('data-id');
} else if (getUpcomingSlide?.classList.contains('locations-slide--upcoming-event')) {
//                         ^--- here
  var setActiveSlidePosition = getUpcomingSlide.getAttribute('data-id');
} else {
  var setActiveSlidePosition = 0;
}
```

The key difference is that:

> instead of causing an error if a reference is nullish (`null` or `undefined`), the expression short-circuits with a return value of `undefined`

And since `undefined` is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), the condition will evaluate to `false` and continue with the `if/else` chain.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to check that the element selected by class name contains the class name (it will).  You only need to check if it exists.

```js
var getActiveSlide = document.querySelector(".locations-slide--active");
var getUpcomingSlide = document.querySelector(".locations-slide--upcoming-event");

  if (getActiveSlide) {
    var setActiveSlidePosition = getActiveSlide.getAttribute('data-id');
  } else if (getUpcomingSlide) {
    var setActiveSlidePosition = getUpcomingSlide.getAttribute('data-id');
  } else {
    var setActiveSlidePosition = 0;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the alternative. I think I was making the codes too complicated. :)